# Why Xamarin Forms APK contains "not necessary" assembly reference?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image]

In my code, I'm no using any reference to `System.Xml.Linq.dll, System.Xml.dll`, why they are in my APK (`signed`)?

And how to remove it if it's necessary/possible?

I've removed references in IOs and Android, but APK still contains this DLLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For discarding unused code with xamarin, You can use linker options.

Please see [Linker Options](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/)